# Key prop not being recognized in React

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, express, key, react-props

I have a component called ListSuppliers, in it I have a bootstrap modal, it contains a table, and I want to populate that table from a postgresql table. Below is what I have in my Fragment section for the modal:

```
<div className="modal fade" id="myModal">
            <div className="modal-dialog">
                <div className="modal-content">
                    <div className="modal-header d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <h4 className="modal-title">Supplier Name</h4>
                    </div>
                
                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <h3 className="text-center mt-2">Search Bar</h3>
                        <form>
                            <input 
                            type="text" 
                            className="form-control"      
                            />
                        </form>
                        <table className="table mt-5">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Supplier Name</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {suppliers.map(supplier => (
                                    <tr key={supplier.supplier_id}>
                                        <td>{supplier.supplier_name}</td>
                                        <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteSupplier(supplier.supplier_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                                    </tr>
                                ))}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                
                
                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is what I have for my ListSuppliers components and routes:

```
const ListSuppliers = () => {
    const [suppliers, setSuppliers] = useState([]);


     //Populate modal table function

     const getSuppliers = async () => {
        try {
            
            const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/supplier");
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            setSuppliers(jsonData);


        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
        }
    }


//routes from index.js file
app.get("/supplier", async (req, res) => {

    try {

        const allSuppliers = await pool.query("SELECT supplier_name FROM supplier ORDER BY supplier_id ASC");
        res.json(allSuppliers.rows);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})

//Delete supplier entry

app.delete("/supplier/:id", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {id} = req.params;
        
        const deleteSupplier = await pool.query('DELETE FROM supplier WHERE supplier_id = $1', [id]);

        res.json(id);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})
```

My modal displays the information as intended, however I'm getting this error:

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop
Check the render method of `ListSuppliers`
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error as I included the key prop in table row:

```
{suppliers.map(supplier => (
 <tr key={supplier.supplier_id}>
   <td>{supplier.supplier_name}</td>
   <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteSupplier(supplier.supplier_id)}>Delete</button></td>
 </tr>
))}
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if supplier_id is present.

Lastly, try this and see if the warning comes up

```
{suppliers.map((supplier, index) => (
 <tr key={index}>
   <td>{supplier.supplier_name}</td>
   <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteSupplier(supplier.supplier_id)}>Delete</button></td>
 </tr>
))}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate where I should look for supplier_id? The edit you gave makes the error go away, but I do not know why

Comment: @Vanillaice over here in this line there is no selection of supplier_id. You just selected supplier_name

await pool.query("SELECT supplier_name FROM supplier ORDER BY supplier_id ASC");

The solution I gave you will also work, no problem in that. Try this above suggestion. Select supplier_id also and see.

Comment: Change to this: await pool.query("SELECT supplier_name, supplier_id FROM supplier ORDER BY supplier_id ASC");

Then do key={supplier.supplier_id}

As per the docs, react needs unique keys to identify what has updated, added or removed for its internal working. Read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I updated the OP to include a delete route for further clarity. I'm confused because the approach I posted is the one I used with other tables and I never had any issues. So since I was getting issues at this particular time I assumed it had something to do with the modal. For example replacing all the key words from 'supplier' to say 'producer' works exactly as expected, so I'm thinking it really was an issue with my supplier_id not existing somewhere?

Comment: Yes, supplier_id was not existing thats why the issue. You need unique id fetched to use in key prop. Otherwise key={index} will also work since unique id is not present. It wont create any issue :)

Comment: So changing my select query to 'SELECT supplier_name, supplier_id FROM supplier ORDER BY supplier_id ASC' worked, but at this point I'm curious why would my original approach work in the first place? For example I have a table "Producer", and it's identical to my "Suppliers" query in the OP. Why would the mapping work for "Producer" if my select query never included the Producer_id column, while the supplier_id column is required for table Supplier?

Comment: much love for helping me out

Comment: Happy to help. Time to give back to the community :)

Comment: @Vanillaice For the producer, I need to see the code then I can say exactly why it worked :)